# How do I hide one word from a view result column

Tags: 7, views, workbench

I have a view which displays content overview using a table. I have joined two columns, a and b, in the table.

[image]

I want the column to display like the red square... currently they show as the red ellipse. Column a is "moderation state" and column b is "publish time".

Comment: The red rectangle shows only column b (publish time). If that is what you want, why joining two columns.

Comment: i did the red box as an example of how i want it to look.. i want the State to show if its published or draft or needs review if its published it just shows the time & date else it just shows the state its in currently but in the same column.

Comment: This seems to call for a conditional field. You can use the customfield module (http://drupal.org/project/views_customfield) to add a PHP enabled field. This custom field should rewrite column a based on its content (thus hide if Published).

Comment: Please note that this is for Drupal6. In Drupal7 you want to use the Views PHP module (http://drupal.org/project/views_php).

Comment: Thanx paul... i sinsatlled the module and added a global php filter.. but it doesnt do anything.. what i have is 
$stat=row->state;
if($stat=="published"){
substr($stat, 6);
}

Comment: You have to *return* some value.

Comment: i coded it in some other way using some if statements but its working alright :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I want to display an item from two different tables, I used an if-else statement.

```
if ($row->state == 'published') {
  echo "$date"; 
}
else {
  echo "$row->state";
}
```